# Wrong server time zone MySql. Why the command in MySql-shell is incorrect?

Tags: mysql, shell, timezone

1. When i use this command:

   MySQL JS > SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+3:00';
2. i see the next error:

   SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Answer (score 0):

Edit the my.ini(cnf

and add

```
[mysqld]
default-time-zone = "+03:00"
```

Amd so the3 time_zone is changed even when the server restarts

or run as ayou need higher rights to do this

```
sudo mysql -e "SET GLOBAL time_zone = ‘+3:00’;"
```

Answer (score 0):

It fails because you are using a `mysqlsh` JS shell that expects JavaScript, but you are entering a `mysql` CLI command.

If this was unintentional, you can run `mysql` instead of `mysqlsh` to get the classic CLI interface that most online resources are written for.

Comment: thanks, but in 2nd/3rd ways you propose, i have an error like: ERROR: Not connected. 4th way - error like: TypeError: Cannot read property 'runSql' of null. And only 1st way - was successful for me.